# How to logout KDE forcely from the command?

Tags: centos, kde

In my project, if the process receives some specific messages, it will run a script to logout the KDE desktop forcely even there are some unsaved data in the application.

I searched in Google and got the following command:
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout 0 0 2

The above command works fine if there are no applications to block the logout. But if there are unsaved data in some applications, the application will pop a dialog to block the logout, such as the application "kwrite":
[image: The app kwrite pop a dialog to block the logout]

I referred the KDE doc:
http://git.net/ml/kde-users/2014-03/msg00040.html

It seems the third parameter "2" passed to the org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout means the application "kwrite" should be killed immediately instead of pop-up dialog. But it doesn't work.
 Is there any expert know the reason that why the third parameter "2" doesn't work? How can I logout the KDE forcely even if the application "kwrite" is running with the un-saved date?

My KDE version is kdebase-workspace-4.3.4-30.el6_6.x86_64 and the distribution is CentOS 6.7.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be graceful, you could try `killall -9 plasma-desktop`. You might have to adjust the process name.

Be careful with this if there will be multiple users with active KDE sessions. Might be a good idea to stick the PID in a variable by evaluating something like `ps aux | grep plasma-desktop | grep $USER | awk '{print $2}'` and `kill -9 $PID` instead.

Comment: Thanks your solution. Yes, it can work. Do you know why the third parameter "2" can't logout forcely? Is it a KDE issue?

Comment: I don't, but it looks like it was never meant to handle ungraceful logouts like what you're looking to do here (probably to protect users). My solution is basically a sledgehammer approach and something that should be avoided in most situations because data loss can occur.